# Anybody still have HP C8000 discs anywhere by any chance?

Tags: hp-ux

I know it's a long shot, but here goes:
I need an ISO image of the "HP C8000 Core Graphics" CD that came with the HP C8000 PA-RISC workstation. I was not able (and trust me, I've looked VERY thoroughly) to find it anywhere. I managed to dig up the HP-UX install CDs as well as the hardware enablement patch for HP-UX 11i v1 , so I have a working system. It does not run the graphics at full speed as it's equipped with a FireGL T2 card that needs the aforementioned CD, or rather the X server and drivers from it - these are not part of the OS or the enablement patch.
Appreciate if anybody can help.

Comment: According to [this post](https://unixforum.net/index.php/topic,2749.msg19817.html#msg19817) on a German forum you can install "B6268AA HP-UX 11.11 Graphics Technical Computing Environment" to get it running. Do you have this CD?

Comment: @Freddy no I don't. For some reason this stuff is impossible to get hold of. Oracle (previously SUN) at least still has downloads and patches for older versions of Solaris available, so resurecting retro sparc boxes is not a big problem. Turns out HP removed everything on hp-ux from their web site and ftp (even patches). Google also does not seem to have much aside from pdf manuals that reference the downloads and have links to stuff HP no longer has. The Wayback Machine also has nothing. Even tried TPB - no joy :( I really want to compile and play Quake II with OpenGL on my pa-risc box!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a request for some stuff.

Comment: I own a C8000 - I could help you figure out what you really need if you still need help

Comment: Let me elaborate:
You need:
1. PHSS_34389, then
2. HWEnable11i_B.11.11.0612.458.depot
This will get your FireGL running and when X loads it will stop complaining you have no acceleration.
Then
3: B6268AA_B.11.11.20.12_HP-UX_B.11.11_32_64.depot gives you TCOE and all the OpenGL goodness.

However, you still can't build anything:
GCC is not compatible with HPs OpenGL libraries in their optimised form (thread local storage issues). You can still build, but then what's the point.
X libraries are not included, for that you will need B3394BA (HP-UX Developer's Toolkit) and HP's compiler.

Comment: @Shiunbird WOW never thought that someone would answer after so much time :) I have the HP C compiler (getting GCC to run on hp-ux is a pain in itself as hp-ux ld is very outdated). I got the HWEnable11i_B.11.11.0612.458.depot file. Now, any chance You have the other two files somewhere? I've been trying to find them, sadly exactly zero luck...

Comment: I'm a beginner programmer very much interested in porting some software over, so any help is welcome. =)

I can help you get up to speed with GCC as well. I managed to get it working the day before yesterday. The are some particularities to everything in HP-UX but HP's documentation is easily available and truly excellent.

Please contact me on my gmail (just my nickname at gmail).